# Meaning of a continuous action (the action takes some time before I can do it or the action itself takes some time to be done )

Tags: meaning-in-context

I will be **pulling** this video down soon

pulling: does the continuous  mean it will take a little  time(soon) before I can do it or does it mean that "pulling down  a video" takes some time .First I am talking about the gap between the idea and  the realisation of this idea and secondly I am talking about the action itself
Both may be ? but the second seems to me better to justify the use of continuous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare with “I will pull the video down soon” which also means that you won’t do it immediately.  As you suggest “will be pulling” indicates that it will take a little time, although “will pull” says nothing about how long the process will take.